# AWS Storage Gateway and Server 2012 R2

Tags: amazon-web-services, windows-server-2012, gateway, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm having a heckuva time getting the storage gateway VM to authorize: it's not open on port 80. Perhaps I did something wrong?

- Server 2012 R2
- Hyper-V

I downloaded the VM but it would not import. A KB article indicated the problem may be that the VM was exported in Server 2012, or 2008. Applying the workaround, I created a new VM, used the disk from the downloaded VM.

Walking through the steps on the Hypervisor - all goes well - until it's time to input the IP address and click 'continue'. Based on past experience, the browser opens up http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and does it's thing.

Mine does not: IE and Firefox both insist the address is not running http.

- I can ping the address from the host(s) I'm running the browser from.
- I believe the port is not open on the VM - when I issue 'telnet
  x.x.x.x 80' it reports port is not open.
- The VM can run the connectivity tests to AWS-East and West: they pass 'ok'.

I'm super-confused.

I conjecture the exported VM has some mojo in it that I'm not bright enough to duplicate locally.

Help, tips, advice, commiseration - in any and all amounts appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue.  Then I double checked the system requirements and realized I had not allocated enough RAM (8G).  Once I did this, I was able to browse to the gateway and port 80 responded to telnet.

Hope this helps on an old post.